# Hang with custom Declare caption Format

Tags: captions

I am using `\DeclareCaptionFormat` to define my own format. However, I want them to be based on the hang format, so that text is indented. So far, I haven't been able to do this.
MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{customtab}
{\setstretch{0.3}
\textbf{#1#2}\textit{ #3}\hrulefill
}
\captionsetup[table]{format=customtab}
\captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption[Example of a temperature and strain-dependent behaviour table]{Example of a table which defines temperature and strain-dependent behaviour with MAT\_213}
\input{Mat213}
\label{tab:mat213}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

I want the following:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: Your code is not compilable: we do not have Mat213.

Comment: @Bernard the table content is irrelevant

Comment: Sure , but there's a compilation error.

Comment: @Bernard Please use any tabular instead.

Answer (score 1):

I finally could compile commenting `\input{Mat213}`. Simply use the hang format:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    %\DeclareCaptionFormat{customtab}
    %{\setstretch{0.3}
    %\textbf{#1#2}\textit{ #3}\hrulefill
    %}
    \captionsetup[table]{format = hang}%{format=customtab}
    \captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption[Example of a temperature and strain-dependent behaviour table]{Example of a table which defines temperature and strain-dependent behaviour with MAT\_213}
    %\input{Mat213}
    \label{tab:mat213}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I want. I need the custom formatting and line below.

Comment: But you wrote you wanted your caption text to be indented??

Comment: yes, and also! to define my custom format.

Comment: Using `\captionsetup{…}`  is enough to do so. Needless to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you provide an example with both the hang option and my desired format?

Comment: You could add this code to the preamble: `\DeclareCaptionFormat{customtab}{\captionsetup{format = hang, textfont= it}#1#2#3 \par}`.